# HazelCast - Expiration listener delay

Tags: java, listener, delay, hazelcast

The problem is that map listener raised 3-5 seconds after TTL expiration.

Here i add new entry to map

```
05-11-2018 14:38:57.197 INFO  [hz._hzInstance_1_3cc39d15-29b8-4f59-8bca-e47eae0476a1.event-26] MyEntryExpiredListener - :::::::::::entry was ADDED to the map  :::::::::::::::::::
```

TTL configured to 10 seconds but return after ~14 seconds.

```
05-11-2018 14:39:11.326 INFO  [hz._hzInstance_1_3cc39d15-29b8-4f59-8bca-e47eae0476a1.event-26] MyEntryExpiredListener - :::::::::::entry was EXPIRED in the map  :::::::::::::::::::
```

I tried to set configuration properties:

```
 hazelcast.internal.map.expiration.cleanup.percentage=100,
 hazelcast.internal.map.expiration.task.period.seconds=1,
```

Anyone have experience and solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The expiration in Hazelcast works in two ways:

1. The entry is invalid after TTL/max-idle-second duration. When you try to get the entry after TTL/max-idle-seconds, you will get a `null` value.
2. A background process (called expiration task) works and cleans up the expired entries. This task can be optimized with the properties you mentioned.

After the expiration, an `EntryEvent` will be fired if any listeners are added. However, this doesn't guarantee that you will receive this event as the exact time as the event is fired. The eventing system in Hazelcast works asynchronously and is based on fire-on-forget. The event might wait for some time in the event queue. Thus, it is normal to see the time difference between your TTL value & event firing.